herd-lite and composer changed my php.ini location
I'm new to PHP, but I need a CodeIgniter 4 project. I downloaded php 8.3.12 and added it to the environment variables (I'm using Windows 10). After that I installed composer with the setup-exe and here comes my problem.
Composer came with herd-lite, which has overriden my php configuration. Now when I type php --ini I get:
Configuration File (php.ini) Path:
Loaded Configuration File:         C:\Users\User\.config\herd-lite\bin\php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)

I explored that directory and there is nearly nothing except the php.ini and the php executable. However I need the php extensions as well, but with herd I don't get a single extension.
Any idea how can I make composer use my php directory instead of herd?

I haven't installed Composer from scratch for quite long, just self-updating the original setup, but it feels weird that it bundles a whole PHP development environment. Did you get it from the official site getcomposer.org or from somewhere else? You can check where your php.exe file is located with the where command. If you don't need Herd, you'd better uninstall it first.

I got it from the official site. where gave me two paths for php, the first one is herd, the second is my own setup. Im definietly going to remove herd and see if it solves it. Thank you for the tipp.

Finally I solved the problem. The solution was the following:
I noticed with where that I have two environment variable for php.
Composer added an additional path variable that pointed to herd's php and it suppressed mine, because it was above in the Path list. I changed the priority of that by going to Edit system environment variables > Environment variables... > User variables for User > Path > Edit... and here I selected my own php variable and with Move up... I put it above herd's.
